# Live-action movie where a brontosaurus-like dinosaur is hurt in a cave

Tags: story-identification, movie, dinosaurs

More than 10 years back, I  watched a live-action movie on television where a brontosaurus kind of dinosaur is wounded in a cave with a man and a kid near it. The humans look civilized and it's definitely not from the Jurassic Park series.

All I remember is that dinosaur is wounded on its side and probably dies afterwards. It's from a Hollywood movie. This scene happens during the night. There's only one brontosaurus (or any harmless kind of dinosaur), injured and a 30-40 year old man and a kid beside it. They both are sad. It's in a cave like setting. Their clothes are normal ones as far as I remember

I have searched all over the internet and couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: There was a movie called Babe, about a family of saurpods in the deepest african jungle- I think there was at least one sequel.

Comment: Also it might be one of the "Journey to the center of the Earth", based on Jules Vernes' book, film adaptations from the mid-2000s. Surprisingly, at least one of these movies had dinosaurs if I recall...

Comment: It's baby- secret of the lost legend, there are no sequels for that  movie. I came across this result , I'm not sure. Does the dinosaur die/get injured in the movie? @nu'daq

Comment: 1959,1989,1993,2004 I haven't noticed any such scenes in these movies. I you have noticed, please let me know. And it's definitely not the 2008 versions, I would remember if it were from them. @loki

Comment: @nithin You're right I think. In the 2008 version there's a scene with a man (B. Fraser of "The Mummy" fame), a kid and a T-Rex, that's why I was confused.

Comment: Where the humans and dinosaurs living together (and not with the dinosaurs trying to eat/kill the humans)?

Comment: @Nithin- iirc the young dinosaur loses his father to poachers.

Comment: The above scene is the only thing I remember, there's only one brontosaurus(or any harmless  kind of dinosaur), injured and a 30-40 year old man and a kid beside it. They both are sad. It's in a cave like setting. Their clothes are normal ones as far as I remember.

Comment: Any updates guys?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Brontosaurus is an herbivore?

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it the movie ["Dinosaurus!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaurus!)?

In the story they dig up a Tyrannosaurus and a Brontosaurus along with a caveman. The Brontosaurus and the caveman become good friends with the child main character, however the Brontosaurus is gravely wounded by the Rex after a fight and dies shortly after.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is [Loch Ness](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/loch_ness) (1996). The scene described is near the ending.

[image: Title screen for "Loch Ness"]

An image taken from the movie, you can see the kid and the dinosaur in the cave.
[image: Cave, kid, and dinosaur]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could make this a better answer if you [edit] it to include some details of the movie and show how it matches the question.